# Changing margin-top to div in CSS

Tags: css, html, margin

I am trying to change the margin-top property of a div in a WordPress theme, however it does not seem to work. I have added the following line to the custom css stylesheet:

```
 div#primary {
     display: block;
     margin-top:50px;
   }
```

However the div whose property I want to change does not move down. The example can be found at the following URL: http://who.designbond.co.uk/contact-2/
The div I need to move down is the one containing the text of Phylosophy. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div#primary {
     display: block;
     margin-top:50px !important;
}
```

I know it's not a good thing to do (adding !important), but it can help.

Answer (score 4):

That `div` has an inline style with `margin-top: 0px`, which is overriding your stylesheet.

You need to remove or modify that inline style, or (in a pinch, and don't tell anyone I said this) add `!important` to your stylesheet rule).

Comment: by 20 seconds ... damn you :)

Answer (score 2):

Something is setting some inline styling on that div. You can override it using `!important`.

```
#primary {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

Also, since there is an id on that element you css selector can be simplified to `#primary` instead of `div#primary`

Answer (score 2):

I see that the div with id primary has a in line stylesheet. Inline style sheet takes priority over class based style sheet. Your inline stylesheet has margin-top:0px, which is ignoring your class based styling. remove it and it will work.

Comment: Is there any other way of overriding the inline style because I'd prefer not to introduce any changes in the files.

Comment: well then try modifying/adding margin to div with id="content" that will probably lead you to same effect, also i noticed that you added your own div#primary, this wont work because on responsive.css line 202 there is already a class with stylesheet specified. I suggest you go through you stylesheet, first find what you want to edit is there or not(which will be available for most time) and if not then add your stylesheet at correct place.